# Saving and loading multiple models with the same graph in TensorFlow Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In the TensorFlow Functional API guide, there's an example shown where multiple models are created using the same graph of layers. (https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/functional#using_the_same_graph_of_layers_to_define_multiple_models)

```py
encoder_input = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name='img')
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(encoder_input)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(x)
encoder_output = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)

encoder = keras.Model(encoder_input, encoder_output, name='encoder')
encoder.summary()

x = layers.Reshape((4, 4, 1))(encoder_output)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D(3)(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, 3, activation='relu')(x)
decoder_output = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation='relu')(x)

autoencoder = keras.Model(encoder_input, decoder_output, name='autoencoder')
autoencoder.summary()
```

Is it possible to save and load these two models while still sharing the same graph? If I save and load them in the following way:

```py
# Save
encoder.save('encoder.h5')
autoencoder.save('autoencoder.h5')

# Load
new_encoder = keras.models.load_model('encoder.h5')
new_autoencoder = keras.models.load_model('autoencoder.h5')
```

the new encoder and autoencoder will no longer share the same graph, and therefore no longer train together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a cool question. The encoder and autoencoder no longer share the same graph because they are being saved as disjoint models. In fact, `encoder` is being saved twice, as it is also embedded in `autoencoder`.

To restore both models while still sharing the same graph, I would suggest the following approach:

1. Name the `encoder`'s output layer. For example:

   ```
   encoder_output = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(name='encoder_output')(x)
   ```
2. Save only the `autoencoder`:

   ```
   autoencoder.save('autoencoder.h5')
   ```
3. Restore the `autoencoder`:

   ```
   new_autoencoder = keras.models.load_model('autoencoder.h5')
   ```
4. Reconstruct the `encoder`'s graph from the restored `autoencoder` so that they share the common layers:

   ```
   encoder_input = new_autoencoder.get_layer('img').input
   encoder_output = new_autoencoder.get_layer('encoder_output').output
   new_encoder = keras.Model(encoder_input, encoder_output)
   ```

Alternatively, you could also save/load the weights and reconstruct the graphs manually.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great solution It'll definitely work for what I need.